# Select from one column and insert into another column with some string appended?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table `countries` with three columns `country_name, country_code, country_flag`.

The table has 250 rows but the `country_flag` column is all null at the moment because I have created it now.

The purpose of this column is to contain a path to the flag file (Image) of that country like `Images\Flags\UK.gif` (each flag file is named as the country code). Now I want to write a query that should pick country code from the `country_code` column and append the `Images\Flags\` string at the start and `.gif` at the end, something like this

```
'Images\Flags\' + country_code + '.gif'
```

and then update the `country_flag` column with this value.

If this is possible then it will update the table with less effort and I'll get all image paths in the `country_flag` column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
Update countries set country_flag = 'Images\Flags\' + country_code + '.gif'
```

Comment: pleasures mine dude, happy coding :)